# How to replace .js file content based on number of calls

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

I do have a site which calls a javascript file located outside of my site. What i want is that it's content gets replaced once every X calls repeadetly.
First i thought i could use Node.js and use a function like this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var Chance = require('chance');
 
var chance = new Chance();
 
app.get('/get-javascript-file', function(req, res) {
    if (chance.integer({min: 1, max: 10}) == 1) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/someFile.js'));
    } else {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/someOtherFile.js'));
    }
});
 
app.listen(80);
```

But as you can see the script itself replaces js file with another one. I was hoping i could do somehow the same with just one js file.

Comment: If you want to replace something you need two things.

Comment: Can't it be done if I call a Php file which does the same exact thing?!